# js countdown break my angularjs code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, countdown

I'm little disapointed about my countdown function :

```
/* countDowner */
var countDown = 5;
function countDowner() {
    if (countDown < 0) {
        $("#warning").fadeOut(2000);
        var countDown = 0;
        return; // quit
    } else {
        $scope.countDown_text = countDown; // update scope
        setTimeout(countDowner, 1000); // loop it again
        countDown--; // -1
    }
}
$scope.countDown_text = countDown;
countDowner();
```

i put it in a angularjs ctrl and it's break my code :/ there is an error but it's for other code. when i remove my countdown all is working good. what's wrong in my countdown ?

Comment: Don't use jQuery in Angular.js.

Comment: Create a jsbin. Also, call the setTimeout after you have decremented the `countDown` var.

Comment: In angularjs $timeout should be favoured over setTimeout

Comment: Also, having countDown and countDown_text seems unnecessary since they are identical in everyway. I would stick with $scope.countDown and use that in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the code does not work is because you have re-declared the countDown variable.

```
// initialization
var countDown = 5;
// later ...
var countDown = 0;
```

Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/6vkyezbu/